# How do you animate NSCollectionLayoutVisibleItem for compositional UICollectionViewLayouts?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying out the new compositional layout APIs introduced with iOS13, they're pretty great - but I'm having an issue with one thing in particular and there's very little official documentation about it.

I'm looking to perform an animation on a `NSCollectionLayoutVisibleItem` object using `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler`. I've tried two different approaches so far:

1. Using `UIView` property animators

```swift
layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (visibleItems, offset, env) in
    let normalizedOffsetX = offset.x + centeredPadding
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: normalizedOffsetX + collectionView.bounds.width / 2, y: 20)
    visibleItems.forEach({ item in
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
             item.transform = item.frame.contains(centerPoint) ? .identity : CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
         }
    })
}
```

2. Using `CATransaction` animators

```swift
layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (visibleItems, offset, env) in
    let normalizedOffsetX = offset.x + centeredPadding
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: normalizedOffsetX + collectionView.bounds.width / 2, y: 20)
    visibleItems.forEach({ item in
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            item.transform = item.frame.contains(centerPoint) ? .identity : CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }
        CATransaction.commit()
    })
}
```

Neither of these approaches work - however, although not animated, I do see the `transform` changes reflected on the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just discovered how to do this and hopefully this will help someone else. The key seems to be to use the `indexPath` property on the `NSCollectionLayoutVisibleItem` to then retrieve the `UITableViewCell` from the `UICollectionView` and perform any animations on it instead.

Here's how I ended up solving my problem:

```swift
layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (visibleItems, offset, env) in
    let normalizedOffsetX = offset.x + centeredPadding
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: normalizedOffsetX + collectionView.bounds.width / 2, y: 20)
    visibleItems.forEach({ item in
           guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: item.indexPath) else { return }
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                cell.transform = item.frame.contains(centerPoint) ? .identity : CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
           }
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also play around with this if you want a different effect! kind of 3D

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in
      items.forEach { item in
        let distanceFromCenter = abs((item.frame.midX - offset.x) - environment.container.contentSize.width / 2.0)
       let minScale: CGFloat = 0.9
        let maxScale: CGFloat = 1.2
        let scale = max(maxScale - (distanceFromCenter / environment.container.contentSize.width), minScale)
        item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
      }
    }
```